# iPhone Notification on Bluetooth Connection/Connection loss

Tags: iphone, connection, bluetooth, message, loss

is there a kind of message the iOS sends when a Bluetooth device connects or disconnects? Like a broadcast Intent in Android? I'm looking for something like this, so i don't have to check in regular intervals if a device is still connected or not.

Comment: No currently not. Google says it is a game developing kit, but i don't have any experience with it.

Comment: i took a closer look at it and found a message on connection loss.

Comment: is there also a way to receive a message on auto connect of a device?

Comment: this might be interesting for you? http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/07/bluetooth-and-ios-use-bluetooth-in-your-iphone-apps/#.UpSj8mRXmAY